# Android overlay item

Tags: android, overlay

I want to create an overlay item so if a user taps on the overlay item then a dialog with list view pops up. How do I do this?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your own overlay by extending `ItemizedOverlay`. You can override the `onTap()` method to do whatever you want when an item is tapped.

Basic silly example:

```
public class CustomOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {
    private Activity mContext;


    public CustomOverlay(Activity activity, Drawable defaultIcon) {
        super(defaultIcon);
        mContext = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onTap(int index) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).setItems(...
        /* Etc. - You can show the dialog here. */
    }
}
```